# query en MYSQL de sistema de encuestas PHP

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin, mysql-workbench

estoy intentando modificar un query en MySQL para poder mostrar una grafica de forma distinta, es un sistema de votación, el siguiente query

```
SELECT preguntas.id_pregunta, preguntas.titulo,COUNT('preguntas.titulo') as count, opciones.valor 
                  FROM opciones 
                  INNER JOIN preguntas ON opciones.id_pregunta=preguntas.id_pregunta 
                  INNER JOIN resultados ON opciones.id_opcion=resultados.id_opcion 
                  WHERE preguntas.id_pregunta = 1 
                  GROUP BY opciones.valor 
                  ORDER BY preguntas.id_pregunta
```

me muestra un conteo de cuantos clientes votaron por las 3 opciones que hay en la pregunta 1, muestra el siguiente resultado

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Hasta ahi todo bien, el tema es que ahora se necesita que al momento de realizar la votación se le de prioridad a un porcentaje de participacion que tiene cada usuario que va a votar, para ello he agregado un campo mas a la tabla Usuarios

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Por ejemplo si el usuario 303177 vota en la pregunta 1 como el tiene un porcentaje de participacion de 72, entenderia que se tiene que hacer un sum por este campo dependiendo la opcion que elija, el tema es que no he logrado unir todas estas tablas ya que me arroja valores bastantes repetidos

la consulta que estaba construyendo es la siguiente

```
SELECT DISTINCT
 u.id_usuario
,p.id_pregunta
,p.titulo
,o.valor
,u.porcentaje_participacion

FROM usuarios as u
inner join usuarios_encuestas as ue on ue.id_usuario=u.id_usuario
inner join encuestas as en on en.id_encuesta=ue.id_encuesta
inner join preguntas p on p.id_encuesta=en.id_encuesta
inner join opciones o on o.id_pregunta=p.id_pregunta
inner join resultados r on r.id_opcion=o.id_opcion

where p.id_pregunta=3
```

y me arroja este resultado de valores repetidos

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Y no se como hacer para poder realizar ese SUM y me de prioridad según el porcentaje de participación del usuario que vote y lo pueda mostrar en la grafica del sistema

Estas son las definiciones de las tablas

```
CREATE TABLE `encuestas` (
  `id_encuesta` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_usuario` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `titulo` varchar(150) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `descripcion` text COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `estado` tinyint(1) NOT NULL,
  `fecha_inicio` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
  `fecha_final` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla `opciones`

CREATE TABLE `opciones` (
  `id_opcion` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_pregunta` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `valor` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;


-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla `preguntas`

CREATE TABLE `preguntas` (
  `id_pregunta` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_encuesta` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `titulo` varchar(150) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `id_tipo_pregunta` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla `resultados`
--

CREATE TABLE `resultados` (
  `id_resultado` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `id_opcion` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;


CREATE TABLE `usuarios` (
  `id_usuario` varchar(15) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `clave` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `nombres` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `apellidos` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `email` varchar(50) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `id_tipo_usuario` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;

-- Estructura de tabla para la tabla `usuarios_encuestas`
--

CREATE TABLE `usuarios_encuestas` (
  `id_usuario` varchar(15) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
  `id_encuesta` int(11) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
```

Ayuda porfavor no se como hacer

Comment: ¿Porcentaje de participación es un porcentaje (100 corresponde a un voto completo, 200 a dos votos y 50 la mitad de un voto) o un peso (algunos tendrán más peso en su votación y otros menos)? ¿Podrías compartir la definición de las tablas y algunos valores de ejemplo para poder reproducir tu problema?

Comment: @OscarGarcia listo, he editado la pregunta añadiendo la definicion y estructura de las tablas , los valores de los usuarios estan un poco arriba

Comment: Gracias, aunque no me sirve demasiado una captura de pantalla. Es mejor la salida de [`SHOW CREATE TABLE nombre_de_tabla`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/show-create-table.html). Por ejemplo, `SHOW CREATE TABLE opciones`. Edito: parece que usas phpmyadmin, ve al apartado de exportar y exporta a texto las tablas y datos deseadas. Te aparecerán en formato SQL (`CREATE TABLE ..` e `INSERT INTO ..`).

Comment: @OscarGarcia Acabo de editar la pregunta colocando lo que exporte de phpmyadmin

Comment: Con la estructura actual de las tablas no es posible realizar lo que deseas, porque no existe relación alguna entre las respuestas emitidas y el usuario que ha emitido dicha respuesta. He reproducido tu base de datos en el siguiente enlace: [https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cnbBVyZmHajmVQ4KGTcDZv/0](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cnbBVyZmHajmVQ4KGTcDZv/0). ¿Necesitas que te sugiramos los cambios necesarios para que se pueda realizar la tarea? Además de eso, necesito que respondas la primera pregunta que te hice. Gracias.

Comment: @OscarGarcia Porfavor si me puedes sugerir los cambios necesarios para realizarlos, y con la pregunta que me realizaste si algunos usuarios tendrán mas peso en su votación que otros